# How to modify variables inside a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, this

I have declared variables outside the plugin so I can modify them later like so:

```
$node.ondrag({start:function(){ console.log(this,"start drag"); }});
$node.change({start:function(){ console.log(this,"other function"); }});
```

But apparently if I attach the plugin to another element, the function is overwritten for both.

```
(function($) {
    var startfn, dragfn, endfn;
    $.fn.ondrag = function(opt){
        var obj = this;
        startfn = opt['start']||null;
        this.on("mousedown",function(){ if (startfn) obj.startfn(); });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.change = function(opt){
        startfn = opt['start'];
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So how can I set different variables for every element that uses the plugin?

Comment: need to define the variables within the plugin....also don't recommend using `change` and overrirding same jQuery method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the information in variables, you can use [jQuery's `.data` API](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store it on each element.

E.g.

```
var startfn = opt['start'] || null;
this.data('myplugin.startfn', startfn);
```

If you are doing more advance stuff, I suggest to have a [look at jQuery UI's `$.widget` factory method](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/). It is supposed to make creating stateful plugins easier. It also uses `$.data` under the hood.

Also, as stated in the comment, you shouldn't overwrite an existing jQuery method. It looks like your `.change` function is some kind of a helper function in your plugin. Check out the [jQuery documentation about plugins](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/), under *"Provide Public Access to Secondary Functions as Applicable"*. Basically, you would `.change` a property of the plugin function:

```
$.fn.ondrag.change = function(opt){
    // ...
};
```

Comment: The last solution is great, so my dom object is not full of data attributes.

Comment: You still have to use `.data` to store the actual data. The example is just for structuring your plugin methods. I forgot to remove the code from the body.

Comment: I kind of expected that, I just thought there was a built-in solution with local variables on plugins.